# Kotlin How to add getSharedPreferences() method in nested class

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

1. I have tried to add getSharedPreferences() method in the Nested
   Class. I have tried many ways but failed to add this method in
   theCustomSlide2 Class. Please guide me how I can call
   getSharedPreferences() method in the CustomSlide2 Class. I needs to
   update the flag from CustomSlide2 Class.

   ```
    package com.bangla.os.activity

    import agency.tango.materialintroscreen.MaterialIntroActivity
    import agency.tango.materialintroscreen.SlideFragment
    import agency.tango.materialintroscreen.SlideFragmentBuilder
    import agency.tango.materialintroscreen.widgets.OverScrollViewPager
    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import com.bangla.os.R

    class InitActivity : MaterialIntroActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            if (!getSharedPreferences("quickSettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstStart", true)) {
                skipStart()
                return
            }

            val overScrollLayout = findViewById<View>(agency.tango.materialintroscreen.R.id.view_pager_slides) as OverScrollViewPager
            val viewPager = overScrollLayout.overScrollView
            viewPager.overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER

            addSlide(CustomSlide1())
            addSlide(CustomSlide2())
            addSlide(CustomSlide3())

        }

        override fun onFinish() {
          super.onFinish()
           setState()
        }

        private fun skipStart() {
           setState()
           finish()
        }

        private fun setState() {
           val intent = Intent(this@InitActivity, Home::class.java)
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
           startActivity(intent)
        }

   class CustomSlide1 : SlideFragment() {
       override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
               val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intro_custom_layout, container, false)
               return view
        }
         override fun backgroundColor(): Int = R.color.op_blue
         override fun buttonsColor(): Int = R.color.intro_button_color3
    }


    class CustomSlide2 : SlideFragment() {

      getSharedPreferences("quickSettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("firstStart", false).apply()
      override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
               val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intro_custom_layout_option, container, false)
               return view
       }
       override fun backgroundColor(): Int = R.color.op_blue
       override fun buttonsColor(): Int = R.color.intro_button_color3
    }



    class CustomSlide3 : SlideFragment() {
           override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
                 val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intro_custom_layout_confirm, container, false)
                 return view
           }
           override fun backgroundColor(): Int = R.color.op_blue
            override fun buttonsColor(): Int = R.color.intro_button_color3
      }

    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add getSharedPreferences() statement inside the function.

something like:

```
 class CustomSlide2 : SlideFragment() {

     override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
          val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intro_custom_layout_option, container, false)
          activity.getSharedPreferences("quickSettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("firstStart", false).apply()
          return view
      }

      override fun backgroundColor(): Int = R.color.op_blue
      override fun buttonsColor(): Int = R.color.intro_button_color3
 }
```